# CkRest.AddHeader function does not add a header using Chilkat C++ ("Content-MD5" header using fullRequestBinary PUT)

Tags: amazon-s3, chilkat

We are using Chilkat 9.5.0.80 C++ library.

There is a certain HTTP header we cannot add to our requests: "Content-MD5". When we add this header like this:

`m_ckRest.AddHeader("Content-MD5", "any-value-here");`

and examine the resulting request*, the "Content-MD5" header is NOT present.

However, when we add a header of a different name:

`m_ckRest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");`

... the resulting request DOES contain that header. We are using the "fullRequestBinary" method, for example:

`const char* responseStrPtr = m_ckRest.fullRequestBinary( "PUT", encodedObjectName.c_str(), ckByteDataBuffer);`

* We are examining our requests using a Proxy (using "Fiddler" as an http proxy in between us and Amazon S3 for example to test the upload of a "part" in a multipart AWS S3 upload) and in every attempt, the "Content-MD5" header is NOT present, while other headers are present.

Is this a bug? We found an old forum post from 2013 referencing a very similar sounding problem:  http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/2901/addheader-range-does-not-appear-to-be-effective Does Chilkat remove or ignore our attempt to add a "Content-MD5" header? Is this bug fixed in a version newer than the one we are using? Is there a workaround? Here is an example of the headers in a PUT request:

```
PUT https://our-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/somefile?partNumber=4&uploadId=tJJYIXdxG_7X8elzSJrKt32A_rH46Y0Yk1vyzZgwxpvmK5uCrcE82k_F9UmytVHWuxXfc6tX5o3w.SRnnYcD7VBskcLrr0xC13bHHVDx62iGGQ3eIzkv5J5d1F4_DkcW HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 5266235
x-amz-date: 20200921T201943Z
x-amz-content-sha256: 90fa8fc564dd558d0c2eac92e367d94101f4ca9570c970795b9fdb2aa96d6666
Host: our-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 20:19:43 GMT
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIBYS55OSD2FIOBFUS/20200921/us-west-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=8ea74cb7769d8e158e5ccc0604cc2cdb096703b10c3c8d9323d0746debbdUUU
```

Answer (score 1):

In correspondence with Chilkat support, turns out that Chilkat versions 9.5.0.80 and 9.5.0.83 intentionally remove the `Content-MD5` header when authenticating using `AWS Signature V4`. Instead, Chilkat calculates the SHA256 hash and places it in the `x-amz-content-sha256` (if authenticating using older AWS signature V2, it calculates `Content-MD5` I'm told) So, unlike the comment from @Chilkat Software, this has not been fixed in a later version as of the writing of that comment, and the removal is intentional.

This is not terrible, but it stems from the misunderstanding that a SHA-256 hash of the content is necessary to construct a valid AWS Signature V4 for authentication, when in fact that is *not* the case. While SHA256 is perfectly adequate for content verification, it is also wasteful in comparison to MD5 for content verification.

The AWS C++ SDK itself does not use a SHA-256 hash in the `x-amz-content-sha256` header when uploading a part. I've confirmed it uses: `x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` and instead uses the less "costly" MD5 hash, and puts it in the `Content-MD5` header (see AWS documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html)

> Unsigned payload option – You include the literal string
> UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD when constructing a canonical request, and set the
> same value as the x-amz-content-sha256 header value when sending the
> request to Amazon S3

Here is an example of an Amazon AWS UploadPart request using Content-MD5 for conent verification, and NOT using SHA256 for signing the request (captured from request using AWS SDK for C++):

```
PUT https://mybucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/somefile.mfs01?partNumber=1&uploadId=6CHL6tPKFcRSoxD4iysjKMgQCNfcFAt87bn4fsduV1YI5_aFIz9e36BxFURH_iEX8EChUtQm06qT9oyIUDbAnA.2M.novpBBKsnGl_NqNvVllQ7L1VK6x1PiLlqq46tH HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-MD5: PV204S0m8zJY8zu9Q3EF+w==
Accept: */*
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIBYS55OSD2FOBFUSC/20200923/us-west-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-md5;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=d013028d77e45f3dcce5f46f3fb53cdeeb3c9cfbd931371e69a9925047e61cd3
Host: nuix-nov-dev.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-cpp/1.7.333 Windows/10.0.19041.329 x86 MSVC/1927
amz-sdk-invocation-id: E57D09A7-B5E7-4E2A-8B2D-B493147F06D7
amz-sdk-request: attempt=1
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date: 20200923T212738Z
Content-Length: 5242880
```

Chilkat gave us a new "beta" build that allows us to specify the `Content-MD5` header even for AWS Signature V4 and it won't remove it, however, it's in addition to the automatically calculated SHA-256 `x-amz-content-sha256` so that's doubling the hashing unnecessarily, and would be better to be able to specify `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` for purposes of the AWS signature.

If there is a content mismatch error with the `Content-MD5` value, AWS returns this (with a status 400):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidDigest</Code>
    <Message>The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.</Message>
    <Content-MD5>thisisbad</Content-MD5>
    <RequestId>8274DC9566D4AAA8</RequestId>
    <HostId>H6kSy4cl+54nMon1Hq6AGjmTX/MfTVMQQr8vEVNXUnPlfMtIt8HPdObfusckhBpwpG/CJ6ORWv16c=</HostId>
</Error>
```

If there is a content mismatch with `x-amz-content-sha256` AWS returns the following error, which I had difficulty finding on the web, and is slightly different so pasting here (also status 400):

```
Status:400 : AWSCode: XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch : AWSMessage: The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem should have already been fixed in a later version of Chilkat.